# What is the exact function of F4 key in ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, input-devices, function-keys

what is the function of <kbd>F4</kbd> in Ubuntu? What I have observed is it changes my screen resolution. is there a way to change this setting?

Comment: Generally, no. The f-key functions are assigned by the vendor's BIOS, and not by Ubuntu..

Comment: @mikewhatever You're right. On my laptop, F4 does nothing. Fn+F4 opens the default we browser.

Comment: @mikewhatever if considering your answer right, my laptop as a screen and 2 lines parallel to their opposite sides. on windows it opened project thingy